# Change Similarity per query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, similarity

I know that we can set similarity in mapping but I need to change similarity  at query time. I need scores to be calculated in different ways by changing similarity. Is there any way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

From [Official Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/similarity.html)

> The similarity can be set on the field level when a field is first created, as follows:

So no you cant change it at query time. Im not even sure if you can change it by updating your mapping.